# Combining 2 Arrays on Equal Keys

Tags: php, arrays

How can I combine 2 arrays where `State` of one = `State` of the second AND `ProgramName` of 1 = `ProgramName` of the second given the following array?

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Year] => 2013
        [State] => AK
        [ProgramName] => Medicaid
        [Age21Total] => 56324
        [Age21FFS] => 56324
        [Age21MCO] => 56324
        [Age21Other] => 
        [Under21Total] => 
        [Under21FFS] => 
        [Under21MCO] => 
        [Under21Other] =>
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Year] => 2013
        [State] => AK
        [ProgramName] => Medicaid
        [Age21Total] => 
        [Age21FFS] => 
        [Age21MCO] => 
        [Age21Other] => 
        [Under21Total] => 99085
        [Under21FFS] => 99085
        [Under21MCO] => 99085
        [Under21Other] =>
    )
 [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Year] => 2013
        [State] => AK
        [ProgramName] => CHIP
        [Age21Total] => 563241
        [Age21FFS] => 563241
        [Age21MCO] => 563241
        [Age21Other] => 
        [Under21Total] => 
        [Under21FFS] => 
        [Under21MCO] => 
        [Under21Other] =>
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Year] => 2013
        [State] => AK
        [ProgramName] => CHIP
        [Age21Total] => 
        [Age21FFS] => 
        [Age21MCO] => 
        [Age21Other] => 
        [Under21Total] => 990851
        [Under21FFS] => 990851
        [Under21MCO] => 990851
        [Under21Other] =>
    )
)
```

My attempts:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $rCt; ++$i){
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Total Enrolled'] = $responses[$i]->Age21Total;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['FFS'] = $responses[$i]->Age21FFS;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['MCO'] = $responses[$i]->Age21MCO;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Other'] = $responses[$i]->Age21Other;

        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['Total Enrolled'] = $responses[$i]->Under21Total;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['FFS'] = $responses[$i]->Under21FFS;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['MCO'] = $responses[$i]->Under21MCO;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['Other'] = $responses[$i]->Under21Other;
    }
```

are producing:

```
Array
(
[Medicaid] => Array
    (
        [AK] => Array
            (
                [Age 21+] => Array
                    (
                        [Total Enrolled] => 
                        [FFS] => 
                        [MCO] => 
                        [Other] => 
                    )

                [< Age 21] => Array
                    (
                        [Total Enrolled] => 99085
                        [FFS] => 99085
                        [MCO] => 99085
                        [Other] => 
                    )

            )
```

When I need:

```
Array
(
[Medicaid] => Array
    (
        [AK] => Array
            (
                [Age 21+] => Array
                    (
                        [Total Enrolled] => 56324
                        [FFS] => 56324
                        [MCO] => 56324
                        [Other] => 
                    )

                [< Age 21] => Array
                    (
                        [Total Enrolled] => 99085
                        [FFS] => 99085
                        [MCO] => 99085
                        [Other] => 
                    )

            )
```

So how can I produce the array I need?  I normally would assume array_merge of 2 seperate arrays containing the data, but I would need the merge to happen when the `state` and `programname` are equal for each element

Comment: sheeeeiiiit, is this why the obamacare website has had so many problems?

Comment: little off-topic... ;)  but, yeah I know...  I can only work with what I'm given though when the requirements are.. don't change it, but make it work

Comment: will the new object always want to take these elements: `[Age21Total] => 56324, [Age21FFS] => 56324, [Age21MCO] => 56324` from element 0 and these `[Under21Total] => 99085, [Under21FFS] => 99085, [Under21MCO] => 99085 from element 1

Comment: yes.  the new object needs both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you're looping through your array, the results of the second iteration are trouncing the first. You'll probably want to check to see if `$responses[$i]->Age21Total` is defined or non-empty before assigning it to `$response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Total Enrolled']`, for example.

Edit: To make it more explicit:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rCt; ++$i) {
    if (strlen($responses[$i]->Age21Total) != 0) {
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Total Enrolled'] = $responses[$i]->Age21Total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how will that help get both sets of data into one `record`?

Comment: Here's my thought... 2 loops, one stricktly to populate over21, 1 to populate strictly under 21, then merge the 2... but, they need to merge on `state` and `programname`

Comment: You would only take the data from the record where it's defined. If it's not defined in one, then you don't take it. From the data you've supplied, the "Under 21" data comes from the second record and isn't defined (or it's an empty string) in the first. If you check to see if a given field is defined (or a non-empty string) before copying it into your output structure, then you'll effectively merge them.

Comment: ;) yeah, got that part... now the issue is, when there is blank data for a `record` that particular section is missing from the 2nd array in the question.  Which effectively puts us back at square one.  In otherwords... I still need both sections in the resulting array

Comment: Then initialize the resulting array. First thing you do in the loop, before you start assigning to it from the other two, is do `$response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Total Enrolled'] = ""`. This way all of the required elements will be in the resulting array, and will be filled in if appropriate.

Comment: not sure what you mean?  I do initialize `response_tree` above the loop with `$response_tree = array();`

Answer (score 1):

Will this do it?

```
  for($i = 0; $i < $rCt; ++$i){
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Total Enrolled'] = $responses[0]->Age21Total;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['FFS'] = $responses[0]->Age21FFS;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['MCO'] = $responses[0]->Age21MCO;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['Age 21+']['Other'] = $responses[0]->Age21Other;

        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['Total Enrolled'] = $responses[1]->Under21Total;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['FFS'] = $responses[1]->Under21FFS;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['MCO'] = $responses[1]->Under21MCO;
        $response_tree[$responses[$i]->ProgramName][$responses[$i]->State]['< Age 21']['Other'] = $responses[1]->Under21Other;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately no.  all data is repeated across all states

Comment: would you be able to show a more complete picture of the data structure you need to work with

Comment: well... the initial data structure I'm given is all 50 states structured all like the 1st array in the question... plus another set of 100 records for CHIP as the `ProgramName`   So figure an array with 200 elements, each state structured like the first array in my question... (just editted for the CHIP `ProgramName`

Comment: so you have an array of 50 elements, each of which is an array like the one shown, consisting of two std class objects?

Comment: No.  I have an array of 200 elements... 50 times the 4 std class objects

Comment: ok, yeah, and is it 1 array of 200 elements or 50 arrays of 4 elements?

Comment: 1 array of 200 elements  (uggg)

Comment: ok, and your not interested in the data related to the CHIP program, which (i think) would be elements 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 11, etc..?

Comment: I am interested in it.  Like I said, I basically need to combine the data from the 2 sets  Under 21 and Over 21, into one...  so bring that 200 element array down to 100.  2 for each state... 1 for Medicaid, 1 for CHIP

Comment: sorry, in your code section under 'What i need' you just an array for Medicaid => AK but am I right in thinking what you need is an array with two element Medicaid and CHIP, each of which contains an array of 50 elements (each state), each of which contains two elements (Age > 21, Age <21)?

Comment: no.  100 elements.  2 for each state.  1 for Medicaid, 1 for CHIP.  Each to have data or null values for Under and Over 21 inner elements